# IQKeyboardManagerSwift: Next/Previous buttons invisible

Tags: swift, xcode, testflight, iqkeyboardmanager

I've posted this issue [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1467), but am posting here too in case I have more luck.

In the attached screenshots, the fields are laid out as so:

```
Superview (class IQPreviousNextView)
  Scroll View
    UIStackView ("Content Stack")
      UIStackView ("Input Stack")
        UIStackView ("Diameter Stack")
          UILabel
          UITextField
        UIStackView ("Perimeter Stack")
          UILabel
          UITextField
        UIStackView ("Area Stack")
          UILabel
          UITextField
```

And as you can see, when installing the application to my phone via Xcode, everything works as expected. But archiving + uploading and then using TestFlight seemingly makes these buttons invisible.

On another app I am developing, where this does actually work, I don't use any `UIScrollView`s - only multiple nested `UIStackView`s. Therefore is it possible that it's the `UIScrollView` causing issues?

In AppDelegate, I have this set up with `IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true` and no further configuration.

[image: Installed via Xcode][image: Installed via TestFlight]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by running `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`. Not sure what the issue was - I'm guessing a corrupt installation...

Answer (score 2):

You have to just make UIViewcontoller's base view class of ***IQPreviousNextView***, and all will be fine

Comment: This works like a charm for Swift 5, iOS 14+.

Answer (score 0):

There is another property to hide previousNext button, you should use shouldHidePreviousNext for this.
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/546

Comment: Added `IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysShow` to my AppDelegate.swift (the updated equivalent of your suggestion). I need to wait for the build to archive/upload/process to see results.

Comment: No change unfortunately.